# sbt dependsOn % "compile->compile;test->test"

Tags: scala, sbt

I've been trying to understand what "compile->compile;test->test" is for, but after reading in sbt page still I don't understand it ...

Let's say I have this in build.sbt

```
lazy val `api` = project.dependsOn(`domain` % "compile->compile;test->test")
...
lazy val `domain` = project...
```

What's the difference if I remove "compile->compile;test->test"

```
lazy val `api` = project.dependsOn(`domain`)
...
lazy val `domain` = project...
```

What if I only put "test->test"? Or "compile->compile"?

Comment: AFAIK `compile->compile;test->test` means that the `compile` sources of this project depend on the `compile` sources of the other project; similarly happens with `test->test` wherever that is different to just `dependsOn` I would say no. Why people do it, probably for the same reason we do most of the **sbt** related things, we saw them on some project / pr / issue / chat / blog whose authors we trust and we just cargo-cult copy & paste it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Useful commands to see what is going on are

```
show api / Test / dependencyClasspath
show api / Compile / dependencyClasspath
```

which will reveal the exact classpaths.

> if I remove "compile->compile;test->test"

```
lazy val api = project.dependsOn(domain)
```

is equivalent to

```
lazy val api = project.dependsOn(domain % "compile->compile")
```

and means `api / Compile` configuration depends on `domain / Compile`. If you execute `show api / Test / dependencyClasspath`  then you should see `domain`'s test classpath is not present.

> What if I only put "test->test"?

```
lazy val api = project.dependsOn(domain % "test->test")
```

means `api / Test` depends on `domain / Test` and executing `show api / Test / dependencyClasspath` should reveal `domain`'s `test` classpath being present. However executing `show api / Compile / dependencyClasspath` should reveal `domain`'s `compile` classpath not being present.

Hence if you want `api / Test`  to depend on `domain / Test`, and `api / Compile` to depend on `domain / Compile`, then you have to specify

```
lazy val api = project.dependsOn(domain % "compile->compile;test->test")
```